# Function to count what line a cell with text is in a list

Tags: excel

Hello all I need help but not exactly sure what function I'm needing.

What I'm trying to do is tell how far down a list a value is like "2nd line down, 3rd line down"

Here is the data i have

```
    .HWAG   SHOCK HARDWARE AXLE-DU-21.8X6MM
    .HWAG   1.5MM SPACER

    .HWAO   2MM SPACER
    .HWAO   MOUNTING HARDWARE QUAD XRING 4-014 N70
    .HWAO   SHOCK HARDWARE AXLE-DU-21.8X8MM


    .HWBI   1MM SPACER  
    .HWBI   1.5MM SPACER                   
    .HWBI   2MM SPACER  
    .HWBI   MOUNTING HARDWARE QUAD XRING 4-014 N70  
    .HWBI   SHOCK HARDWARE AXLE-DU-41.0X6MM          
    .HWBI   3.00MM O-RING SPACER W/ ORING INSTALLED
```

so in the .HWAG the cell that contains "AXLE" is on the first line, in .HWAO it is on the third.

so I need to get a formula to tell where it is in a list. and possibly display it like

```
    .HWAG   SHOCK HARDWARE AXLE-DU-21.8X6MM          1
    .HWAG   1.5MM SPACER

    .HWAO   2MM SPACER
    .HWAO   MOUNTING HARDWARE QUAD XRING 4-014 N70
    .HWAO   SHOCK HARDWARE AXLE-DU-21.8X8MM          2

    .HWBI   1MM SPACER  
    .HWBI   1.5MM SPACER    
    .HWBI   2MM SPACER  
    .HWBI   MOUNTING HARDWARE QUAD XRING 4-014 N70  
    .HWBI   SHOCK HARDWARE AXLE-DU-41.0X6MM          5   
    .HWBI   3.00MM O-RING SPACER W/ ORING INSTALLED
```

thank you all

Answer (score 2):

Here, use this. Note: you might need to replace `;` with `,` in formulas.

Formulas:

[image: Formulas]

Result:

[image: Result]